# Nodejs Handlebars How to run serverside javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to use Handlebars on Nodejs.

I can execute plain vars but what if I want to execute javascript code to output some values? 
In PHP we would do this :

```
<div>This is formatted date : &lt;?php echo date($oldDate); ?&gt; </div>
```

Example in nodejs handlebars:

```
<div>This is non formatted date: {{olddate}}</div>
<div>This is formatted date : {{ date(olddate)}}</div>
```

I know that in EJS template engine we can do this by putting inside <% like this

```
<div>This is formatted date : <% date(olddate)%></div>
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, So basically, I can create a custom helper and use it.

Comment: @Jonathan Please write this as an answer so I can choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars doesn't support executing JavaScript expressions, including function calls, within the template. This is likely because it was inspired by [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/)'s "*logic-less templates,*" adding only a minimal amount of logic.

What is uses instead are [helpers](http://handlebarsjs.com/#helpers):

```
<div>This is formatted date : {{date olddate}}</div>
```

And, it allows you to define your own using [`Handlebars.registerHelper()`](http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html#base-registerHelper):

```
Handlerbars.registerHelper('date', function (dateValue) {
    return new Date(dateValue).toString();
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/sznkd4eo/